# Add IP restricted firewall rule in Lightsail with terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-lightsail

I'm building infrastructure in Lightsail with Terraform. Is there a way to add a firewall rule allowing access to a port only from the IP of another instance I create? This is possible through the web UI, but so far I can only find the `aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports` resource, which does not accept an IP restriction list.

Comment: Isn't it the optional `cidrs` property of the `aws_lightsail_instance_public_ports` resource?

Comment: ahhh you might be right. the terraform documentation for that is pretty poor, but the AWS version suggests this is the case. thanks!